# How to override a case class attribute and avoid duplicated storage?

Tags: scala, slick, silhouette

I have an use-case that would take advantage of case class attribute overriding if that was possible in Scala 2.12.x. My use-case is the following: there are multiple case classes in [Play-Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) (P-S) e.g. `LoginInfo` that the library is built upon:

```
case class LoginInfo(providerID: String, providerKey: String)
```

If life would be perfect, these would be traits and not case classes but ok, now in a project that re-uses P-S I'd like to design my Database, customize the Slick code generator and get Slick-mapped database-friendly definitions for those P-S case classes e.g.

```
case class LoginInfoRow(id: Int, override val providerID: String, override val providerKey: String, modified: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None) 
  extends com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo(providerID, providerKey)
```

This approach would allow me to plug my Slick-persistence specialized `LoginInfoRow` to the P-S framework seamlessly. Note that this is auto-generated from the database using Slick + my custom generator changes. The `LoginInfoRow` definition above leads to the compiler error:

```
[error] /home/skywalker/code/play-silhouette-seed/app/models/generated/Tables.scala:29:14: case class LoginInfoRow has case ancestor com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo, but case-to-case inheritance is prohibited. To overcome this limitation, use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes.
[error]   case class LoginInfoRow(id: Int, override val providerID: String, override val providerKey: String, modified: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None) extends com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo(providerID, providerKey)
[error]              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed May 25, 2019 12:06:43 PM
```

A possible solution would be to have different names for those two attributes but it would be confusing from the interface of the `LoginInfoRow` which one to use? and it would also duplicate storage.

What's this compiler proposed alternative `To overcome this limitation, use extractors to pattern match on non-leaf nodes.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an implicit or explicit converter for this scenario.

Implicit converter:

```
implicit def loginInfoRowToLoginInfo(loginInfoRow: LoginInfoRow): LoginInfo = {
  LoginInfo(loginInfoRow.providerID, loginInfoRow.providerKey)
}
```

Explicit converter:

```
case class LoginInfoRow(
  id: Int,
  providerID: String,
  providerKey: String,
  modified: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None
) {
  def toSilhouette: LoginInfo = {
    LoginInfo(providerID, providerKey)
  }
}
```

Or a combination of both.

Comment: Thank you! That would be a solution but I find that refactoring to traits instead of keeping case classes for `AuthInfo` subtypes would be much cleaner. Cleaner in many areas: less complexity, less overhead and prevent the application from having 2X the amount of these `AuthInfo` instances around. Remember I’d need to also have `fromSilhouette` equivalents and have those implicit and conversions affecting my whole App when there is no need to if those `AuthInfo` were traits.

Comment: I also think that there wouldn’t be any impact to the Silhouette code base in terms of backward compatibility. I can do a PoC fork for this.

Comment: I've moved the discussion to https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/issues/559